# How to mock Java 8 Function in Spock Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, mocking, spock

I want to mock Java 8 Function in spock groovy

below is my transformer interface

```java
interface Transformer {
  String doSomething();
  Integer performTest();
  Function<List<Test>, String> findSuccess();
}
```

want to mock this Function in service

```java
transformer.findSuccess().apply(tests);  // service class code
```

Please help me on this

Comment: How about giving it a lambda? Something like `Transformer t = list -> 'stubbed result'` (if you're on groovy 3), or `Transformer t = {it.join('-test-')}`?

Comment: Above is not an FunctionaInterface, I have updated question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using groovy 2.5 and I have added below in my test case. it's working

```groovy
def function = {
  "1234"
} as Function<List<Test>, String>
1 * transformer.findSuccess() >> function
```

Comment: Actually your syntax yields a runtime error during text execution for me, but this works: `1 * transformer.findSuccess() >> (Function) { "1234" }` or of course something like `def function = { "1234" }` and then `1 * transformer.findSuccess() >> function`.

Comment: You do not need `as Function<List<Test>, String>` in this case, but if you want it more type-safe you can do it like that if you prefer. But then I would use `Function<List<Test>, String> function = { "1234" }`. Or you stick with my version, just `def function = { "1234" }` if type inference is okay for you.